# Overlay Google Maps to OpenLayers in GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, google-maps-api

I am new to GeoServer and I want to overlay Google Maps to my OpenLayers in GeoServer, I don't know how to start, do suggest me how to begin.

I want know which file to access, file extension, and what language is being used to incorporate it in GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to incorporate Google Maps with GeoServer. Instead, the Google Maps tiles will go straight into OpenLayers, with your own datasets coming from GeoServer. Something like this rough diagram:

[image]

See the OpenLayers [sample page](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/google-v3.html) for instructions on how to add Google Maps as a background layer:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
projection: 'EPSG:3857',
layers: [
new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Physical", {
  type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
})...
```

Comment: ,In which file should I use this code? and what is the procedure to achieve this, can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: I would start by reading the [OpenLayers Getting Started](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/introduction.html) documentation. Then once you have a good grasp of the basics, see the [Google Maps demo].(http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/google-v3.html)

Comment: Ya I will go through the documentation first and check out how things work. Thanks